# PHP: Is there any native equivalent of compact() that works on arrays

Tags: php

I'd like to know if there is any native way to extract a set of **values and their keys** from **a large array** using **a smaller array of keynames**.

`compact()` does this on separate variables but not on arrays:

```
$foo='foo';
$bar='bar';

print_r(compact('foo','bar'));
// or
print_r(compact(array('foo','bar'));

// Prints:
// Array(
//  [0] => foo,
//  [1] => bar
// )
```

So far I've always used foreach loops, but I started to wonder if a simpler method exists. I've gone through the PHP documentation's *Array functions* section but still felt that I'd try asking in case I missed something.

Comment: You may have a problem: you're already putting on the table a solution to a problem. What if your way of dealing with the problem is wrong and it's based on wrong assumptions or misconceptions? I suggest you just give details about **the actual problem**, and not about **what you think it would be** the right solution.

Comment: Although my quickly written question with a somewhat related example might be a little confusing, I think the mention of the solution I currently use is justified, so people won't waste their time with answering with the same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarise what turned out more lengthy than I anticipated, the functions of interest to you are likely [`array_flip()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) and [`array_intersect_key()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).

---

I hope I correctly understood what you wanted. You want to an array of variable names, where the variables themselves contain array keys, and you want to search a larger array for these keys?

Does this do what you want? I haven't benchmarked it against a foreach, it's quite possibly slower.

```
$foo = 'foo2';
$bar = 'bar3';

$array = array(
    'foo1' => 1,
    'foo2' => 2,
    'foo3' => 3,
    'foo4' => 4,
    'bar1' => 5,
    'bar2' => 6,
    'bar3' => 7,
    'bar4' => 8
);

$keys = array(
    'foo',
    'bar'
);

$extract = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(compact($keys)));

var_dump($extract);
```

Output:

```
array
  'foo2' => int 2
  'bar3' => int 7
```

**Edit:**
From Gordons comment, if the use of `compact` to use variable names as keys is irrelevant, you can substitute in the following code.

```
$keys = array(
    'foo2',
    'bar3'
);

$extract = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
```

You can further reduce the code by defining your array of keys slightly differently, and eliminating the need for `array_flip()`.

```
$keys = array(
    'foo2' => null,
    'bar3' => null
);

$extract = array_intersect_key($array, $keys);
```

Comment: I understood that the variable name (not the variable's content) is the name of the array keys, so you can likely omit the `array_flip(compact())` part

Comment: @Gordon: Good point, I see `compact()` used so rarely it probably threw me off. Would still need `array_flip()` as the list of keys is stored as values, but thats easily solved by defining the array differently.

Comment: I should've read the *array_intersect* section more thoroughly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work with `compact`, you could use the following:

```
function array_subset(array $array, $keys)
{
    extract($array);
    return compact(array_slice(func_get_args(), 1));
}
```

Since `extract` and `compact` use the current symbol table in the function's scope, there will be no pollution of the caller scope whatsoever. This would then be called like this ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sgnkjB)):

```
$subset = array_subset($source, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz');
```

But `array_intersect_key` is likely what you are really after.

Comment: Good answer, but a little too late. +1 for you anyway and thank you